# Zurb Foundation - Remove column for medium screens

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I have a site prototype in Zurb Foundation 3, so far I have the desktop version and now I am adjusting it to be responsible on tablets and mobiles.

What I am strugling with is this: I have some columns with content in a row, and I want to remove some of the columns for medium and small resolutions. But I want the other columns to stretch to the rest of the page width. How do I do this correctly ?

I am using

```
class="hide-for-medium-down"
```

to hide the element, but how do I wrap the content so it stretches when some of the elements is hidden ?

I found two ways but none of them works:
1) I make it as standard row-columns, eg:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="three columns">...</div>
    <div class="three columns">...</div>
    <div class="three columns hide-for-medium-down">...</div>
    <div class="three columns">...</div>
</div>
```

but in this case the third column will just stay as empty space.

2) I can make it using block-grid like this:

```
<ul class="block-grid four-up">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li class="hide-for-medium-down">3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

but this time the 4th column just moves left to the position of 3th and the fourth space will stay empty again.

Closest I got was using the mobile-x-up class to adjust the grid to have lesser columns for mobiles - this way:

```
<ul class="block-grid four-up mobile-three-up">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li class="hide-for-medium-down">3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Unfortunatelly, this only works for mobiles, but I am unable to use this also for tablets on medium resolution as there is no equivalent for this.

So overall my question is: what is the best way to solve this ? And what is the best way to hide elements on smaller screens while still keeping the grid ? Is it even possible to remove elements from grid on medium screens while still keeping the grid working ?

Comment: This will require custom CSS. However you should try to use this technique sparingly. Hiding columns of content defeats many of the benefits of what makes responsive design great. http://www.netmagazine.com/features/five-responsive-web-design-pitfalls-avoid

Answer (score 6):

Not sure which version you are using, but in Foundation 5, try this...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="columns small-3">...</div>
    <div class="columns small-6 large-3">...</div>
    <div class="columns small-3 hide-for-medium-down">...</div>
    <div class="columns small-3">...</div>
</div>
```

or this...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="columns small-3 large-4">...</div>
    <div class="columns small-6 large-4">...</div>
    <div class="columns small-3 hide-for-medium-down">...</div>
    <div class="columns small-3 large-4">...</div>
</div>
```

etc., depending on how you want the remaining columns to fill in the space.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution that I've come up with is to use jQuery to make some changes to specific columns when the browser is resized (or loaded at a certain size).

Something like below (taken directly out of my project file - so you'll have to edit for your specific purposes).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    check_column_size();  
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    check_column_size();
});

function check_column_size() {
    if( $(window).width() >= 768 && $(window).width() <= 800 ) {
        $('section#main').removeClass( 'eight' ).addClass( 'eleven' );
        $('section#sidebar').removeClass( 'hide-for-small' ).addClass( 'hide' );
    } else {
        $('section#main').removeClass( 'eleven' ).addClass( 'eight' );
        $('section#sidebar').removeClass( 'hide' ).addClass( 'hide-for-small' );
    }
}
```

The line that adds / removes the *hide-for-small* class is needed because that class includes the style

```
display:inherit !important;
```

which overrides any attempt to hide/remove the element. So I needed to remove that class, and then add it back on afterwards in-order to successfully hide my element at resolutions more than "small".

Seems to work for my case, but I'm only doing it on one small section. You might run into problems if you're trying to make it happen for many different elements on the page all at once.

Answer (score 2):

You can get this working with duplicate content:

```
<div class="row hide-for-medium-down">
    <div class="three columns">...</div>
    <div class="three columns">...</div>
    <div class="three columns">...</div>
    <div class="three columns">...</div>
</div>
<div class="row show-for-medium-down">
    <div class="four columns">...</div>
    <div class="four columns">...</div>
    <div class="four columns">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

My best recommendation, upgrade your framework... using foundation 5, this code will make what you want: hide a column for mobile/tablet and the columns space evenly.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-4 large-3">...</div>
    <div class="small-4 large-3">...</div>
    <div class="large-3 show-for-large-up">...</div>
    <div class="small-4 large-3">...</div>
</div>
```

The third column will be hidden for mobile and tablet devices, and only 3 columns will be shown; on desktop, four columns of 25% width will be shown.

That's the best way to address this requirement, IMHO

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are looking for CSS media queries. I would suggest you reading over the following page.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Also rather then hiding the content why not resize it so your mobile users can also view it, unless you feel it is a bad design choice!

I hope that helps.

Comment: Justin - take a look at Foundation by Zurb : http://foundation.zurb.com/

It's an advanced responsive framework that makes extensive use of media queries. This question was specific to changing the size of a column set using the Foundation framework and not simply a question about how to use media queries in general.